# Multi-core processing hangs

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing

My code looks like the following. It seems to be "hanging" during the `proc.join()` loop. If I create the dataframe `df` with 10 records, the whole process completes fast, but starting with 10000 (as shown), then the program seems to just hang. I am using `htop` to look at the CPU core usages, and I do see all of them spike up to 100%, but then long after they go back down to 0%, the program doesn't seem to continue. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def do_something(df, partition, q):
    for index in partition:
        q.put([v for v in df.iloc[index]])

def start_parallel_processing(df, partitions):
    q = Queue()
    procs = []
    results = []

    for partition in partitions:
        proc = Process(target=do_something, args=(df, partition, q))
        proc.start()
        procs.extend([proc])

    for i in range(len(partitions)):
        results.append(q.get(True))

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    return results

num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
df = pd.DataFrame([(x, x+1) for x in range(10000)], columns=['x','y'])
partitions = np.array_split(df.index, num_cpus)
results = start_parallel_processing(df, partitions)
len(results)
```

Comment: Your processes are queuing more records than you're de-queuing. You're calling `q.get` `len(paritions)` times, however each process is in-queuing `len(partitions[i])` times. Basically, when you're calling `join`, your processes haven't finished yet. However, they should finish eventually and your program should exit after in-queuing is done by all processes.

Comment: @sirfz that was not the case. `proc.join()` was waiting for indefinitely for a `Queue` that would never get flushed completely

Comment: @martineau if the message is the correct answer you should tag it as "ANSWER" and there will be green checkbox next to my reply, Cheers

Comment: @Mason: Jane Wayne asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `Queue.Queue` doesn't behave as you want and it wasn't made for sharing between multiple process, instead you must use `Manager.Queue()`

I have added some print to understand your code flow,

You can still polish your code to use `Pool()` instead of `num_cpus`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import pprint
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager

def do_something(df, partition, q):
    # print "do_something " + str(len(partition)) + " times"
    for index in partition:
        # print index
        for v in df.iloc[index]:
            #print "sending v to queue: " + str(len(df.iloc[index]))
            q.put(v, False)

    print "task_done(), qsize is "+ str(q.qsize())


def start_parallel_processing(df, partitions):
    m = Manager()
    q = m.Queue()
    procs = []
    results = []
    print "START: launching "+ str(len(partitions)) + " process(es)"
    index = 0
    for partition in partitions:
        print "launching "+ str(len(partitions)) + " process"
        proc = Process(target=do_something, args=(df, partition, q))
        procs.extend([proc])
        proc.start()
        index += 1
        print "launched "+ str(index) + "/" + str(len(partitions)) + " process(es)"

    while True:
        try:
            results.append(q.get( block=False ))
        except:
            print "QUEUE END"
            break

    print pprint.pformat(results)

    process_count = 0
    for proc in procs:
        process_count += 1
        print "joining "+ str(process_count) + "/" + str(len(procs)) + " process(es)"
        proc.join()

    return results

num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
df = pd.DataFrame([(x, x+1) for x in range(10000)], columns=['x','y'])
partitions = np.array_split(df.index, num_cpus)
results = start_parallel_processing(df, partitions)
print "len(results) is: "+ str(len(results))
```

Comment: [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) as you might deduce from the module it is in, was designed precisely for [exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes). You must be confusing it with [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue). The OP is using the one in `multiprocessing`.